# Unable to invalidate data in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am invalidating the data in AWS CloudFront but the changes are not getting reflected on the website. can anyone tell me what problem might be there?
Like I want to invalidate `/dir/abc.html`

With this command its **not working** and **not able to get updates** on the website:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id dfhdhdufhjgh --paths dir/abc.html
```

It's not getting invalidated.

But with this its **working** and able to get **updates** on website:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id dfhdhdufhjgh --paths /dir/
```

I want to know the difference between them.

Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=804846

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `/dir/abc.html` is not in fact what you should be trying to invalidate, in order to accomplish your intended result.  Invalidations need to reference the path actually requested by the browser.  What's the browser actually requesting?

Comment: It is requesting www.Something.com/dir/abc.html

Comment: Is there a query string?  Are there any non-ASCII (multibyte) characters?

Comment: No.. No query string..

Comment: And one more thing if I invalidate this path /dir/ and 15 paths/files are there then invalidation happens for this path only not 15. Right?

Comment: Correct.  Invalidations are billed based only on the number of separate paths you specify -- not how many objects are matched.

Comment: Sorry Michael..  But does it count as 1 or 15? even there are multiple objects that need to be invalidate in that /dir/ path?

Comment: Invalidating `/dir/*` counts as only 1.

Comment: By doing this /dir/* According to the AWS tutorials all the files will get invalidate and all the paths get counted.

Comment: As I stated above, the charge is based on the number of paths you specify, **not** on the number of files matched. Docs: [*The charge to submit an invalidation path is the same regardless of the number of files you're invalidating: a single file (`/images/logo.jpg`) or all of the files that are associated with a distribution (`/*`).*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Comment: I was able to do it by invalidating the path /dir/